# ActionListener Java

Tags: java

У меня есть класс

```
 public class MainWindow extends JFrame implements ActionListener{
         public static void main(String[] args) {
         //интерфейс приложения...
         JButton but1 = new JButton("this is a button 1");
         but1.addActionListner(this);
         }

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {}
}
```

Почему IntelIJ IDEA подчеркивает `this` с такой ошибкой?

> "MainWindow.this" cannot be referenced from a static context

Как это исправить?

Comment: this не доступен из статических методов (в данном случае из main).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`this` это ссылка на экземпляр объекта класса, в статическом контексте экземпляра объекта не существует.

```
class MyClass {
   public boolean checkThis(MyClass obj){
     return this == obj; // this это ссылка на экземпляр этого класса, в данном случае тоже самое что и myClass 
   }

   public static void main(){
     MyClass myClass = new MyClass();
     class.checkThis(myClass); //вернёт true
     // class.checkThis(this); // ошибка, т.к. класс статический и this не существует
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

this - это указатель на текущий экземпляр класса. Так как вызов происходит в статическом методе, то и экземпляра там нет и быть не может.
Тебе необходимо создать экземпляр класса и его передавать вместо this

```
public class MainWindow extends JFrame implements ActionListener{
         public static void main(String[] args) {
         //интерфейс приложения...
         JButton but1 = new JButton("this is a button 1");
         MainWindow listener = new MainWindow();
         but1.addActionListner(listener);
         }

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Дело в том, что `this` это ссылка на созданный объект класса, а метод `main` у Вас статический и в нём объект класса изначально не существует..

Кроме того `main` предназначен для точки входа в приложение, если класс окна Вы назначите главным. Поэтому если уж Вы взялись за `JFrame`, то инициализацию контролов и назначение обработчиков событий нужно выполнять в конструкторе (стандартная практика) или методе класса, в зависимости от задачи.

Не нужно смешивать вход в приложение и работу интерфейса.

Ниже приведу пример формы `JFrame` с учётом всего вышесказанного.

```
public class MyWindow extends JFrame {
    private JPanel contentPane;
    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    MyWindow frame = new MyWindow();
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }
    /**
     * Create the frame.
     */
    public MyWindow() {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
        contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        contentPane.setLayout(new BorderLayout(0, 0));
        setContentPane(contentPane);
        JButton btn1 = new JButton("New button");
        btn1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                btn1.setText("ACTION!");
            }
        });
        contentPane.add(btn1, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    }
}
```